# How to generate two fasta files from samtools phase output?

Tags: sam, fasta, samtools, phase

[samtools phase](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-phase.1.html) is an easy-to-use tool to phase variants from a bam file and a reference.

For a sequence that has two haplotypes, like this:

```
   position: 123456789
haplotype 0: GACCATATT
       SNPs:  **    *
haplotype 1: GTACATACT
```

The output looks like this:

```
CC  M?   chr    PS     pos  allele0 allele1 hetIndex #supports0 #errors0 #supp1 #err1
CC
CC
PS      frame-1   2    9
M1      frame-1  60    2      A       T       1       3       0       23      0
M1      frame-1  60    3      C       A       2       35      1       24      0
M1      frame-1  60    8      T       C       3       46      0       30      0
```

How can I take the reference fasta file and the output of `samtools phase` to generate one `fasta` file for each of the haplotypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer January 20th, 2020.** If you run `samtools phase` with the option `-b my_prefix` it outputs a bam file for both haplotypes, named `my_prefix.0.bam` and `my_prefix.1.bam`. If the sequence has been correctly phased, use these bam files to correct the reference using [pilon](https://github.com/broadinstitute/pilon). This is preferable to the method described in the **January 14th, 2020** answer because pilon will correct SNPs and indels, whereas the python program below will only correct the specific SNPs that `samtools phase` found. `samtools phase` does not find indels.

**Answer January 14th, 2020.** This python program below takes a fasta file as an argument and the output of samtools phase piped in, then prints out a fasta file of the two haplotypes.

Run the program like this:

`samtools phase reads.bam | phase2fasta.py ref.fa > haplotypes.fasta`.

Here is the code of `phase2fasta.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) == 1) or not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    raise Exception("The first and only argument is the reference fasta.")
allele0 = []
seqname = ""
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == ">":
            seqname = line[1:].split(" ")[0].strip()
        else:
            for c in line.strip().upper():
                allele0.append(c)
allele1 = [x for x in allele0]
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line[0:2] == "M1":
        fields = line.strip().split()
        if fields[1] == seqname:
            pos = int(fields[3]) - 1
            allele0[pos] = fields[4]
            allele1[pos] = fields[5]
print(">{}_allele0".format(seqname))
print("".join(allele0))
print(">{}_allele1".format(seqname))
print("".join(allele1))
```

Comment: Oh hey, thanks for this! We need this sort of self-answered post!